# Laravel: include multiple views from modules

Tags: laravel, loops, view, foreach, include

I want to include multiple views in a view from the modules folder.

i have a folder named modules. In that folder i have 2 modules, blog and test.I want to include some views from these modules in another view.

i tried the following:

```
<?php
    $array = ['blog::index','test::test'];
?>

@foreach($array as $result)
    @includeIf($result)
@endforeach
```

It results in only getting the data from the first (blog::index) view 2 times.

Comment: there is a function called 'includeviewsfrom'm it helps you include those extra views directories. You can load them from the modules serviceproviders, did you do that for the test module?